# Is there an adress in the hard disk for each virtual adress?

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory

Is it so that for each virtual adress there exists an adress in the hard disk? But the hard disk can be larger than the virtual memory?

EDIT: Or can some virtual adresses always map to physical, and some map to hard drive which then is loaded to physical adresses?

Comment: not nesseccarily, it is virtual - by definition. It can map pretty much anywhere - from your RAM, hard disk - heck even to a usb connected to your computer. However, it is usually used to map to the RAM

Comment: @nirshahar Thank you, but what if we only have RAM and the hard disk? Will then every adress in the virtual memory correspond to a adress in the hard disk?, and when we use it the OS maps it over to RAM?

Comment: It usually maps to RAM since that is how programs use it. It sometimes may decide to map to the hard disk, for example if there is not enough RAM and a pagination occurs

Comment: @nirshahar Thank you. The way I understood it is that every virtual adress corresponds to an adress in the hard disk. And when you want to use the adress, the adress is loaded from the hard disk to RAM. Is this wrong?

Comment: Virtual address space is usually huge these days, such as 256TB or even 4PB. Most of it "holes", that don't map to anything. That's the default state of virtual memory: not mapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a typical modern operating system, a page frame of RAM can essentially be one of four things:

- Free. Unallocated. Available for use at any time.
- Used by the operating system for its own internal purposes. An OS has data structures, and they need to live somewhere. Page tables might also fall under this general heading.
- A page that represents part of a memory-mapped file. As well as files memory-mapped by user programs, the the text and read-only data of running programs are invariably the executable file memory-mapped. The other main example is buffer cache, where the OS keeps commonly-used data from secondary storage around if it looks like it might be needed.
- "Anonymous memory" (this is the Unix term), which essentially means memory allocated by user programs. The reason why it's called "anonymous memory" is that it's memory that doesn't have a "name", in the sense of a file on disk. Anonymous memory includes user heap-allocated memory, call stacks, and memory shared between processes.

We'll ignore the first two for the moment, because they probably aren't relevant to your question, and just look at the last two.

If the page frame of memory represents part of a file, then it needs to be kept in sync with the copy in secondary storage. If it is a read-only mapping (which is the case for program text), then this is trivial.

If the OS needs more free page frames, and it determines that some piece of read-only file mapping is a good candidate for ejection, it can just be removed from everyone's virtual memory mapping and then freed. If it's read-write, then it may need to be written first, if it's a dirty copy.

If the page frame is anonymous memory, then there is no "file" that it is a copy of. However, all modern operating systems have support for *swap space*, where secondary storage can be used to store anonymous memory in a place other than RAM.

Some older operating systems (e.g. 4.3BSD) did essentially the same thing with anonymous memory as it did with memory-mapped files. All allocated memory was a copy, or cache, of swap space. This meant that you needed at least as much secondary storage dedicated to swap as you had RAM. At some point in the late 80s to mid 90s, this tradeoff made a lot of sense.

Modern operating systems don't do this anymore, and can handle having less swap than RAM, including no swap at all. An operating system may still internally pretend that anonymous memory is kind of a memory-mapped page from a kind of pseudo-device called "swap", but the way its managed is different.

**EDIT**

OK, so that's the perspective of RAM. Now let's talk about the perspective of virtual memory.

Virtual memory is typically organised as a bunch of *segments*. A segment is a contiguous collection of pages which represent a contiguous region of a virtual memory "object". Different operating systems have a different idea about what a virtual memory object can be, but this *usually* means either a file, or anonymous memory.

If a user program tries to access a page which is not part of a segment, then this is what Unix famously calls a segmentation violation.

If a user program tries to access a page which *is* part of a segment, then this is a valid operation. (Assuming that the access itself is valid; you can't write to a read-only segment, for example.)

However, within a segment, a page may or may not be "valid", in the sense that its entry in the CPU's page tables currently points to a page frame of RAM. When a user program tries to access it, this causes a page fault, which traps to the operating system so it can intervene.

In the case of anonymous memory, there are lots of reasons why a page might not be valid:

- When memory is allocated by a program, the OS sets up a segment of anonymous memory, but it does *not* have to be mapped to actual RAM yet, and this can be desirable for speed. It is sufficient that enough memory (whether RAM or swap) to satisfy the allocation *exists*. All modern operating systems let user programs control this.
- The page may be swapped out. In this case, the OS will suspend the thread and read it in.
- The page may be copy-on-write. A page might be shared in such a way that if you only ever read it, you can safely share that copy, but writing to it must force a private copy to be made. I'll give a common example in a moment.
- The OS might just want to do it for its own housekeeping purposes. See [this previous answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66541/what-is-the-need-for-valid-invalid-bit-in-paged-memory-technique/66544#66544) for some examples of when this might occur.

**NOTE** What follows is an explanation of one of the more common uses of copy-on-write memory. This doesn't really answer your question, but I'm including it because you might find it helpful, but feel free to skip or skim.

The use is in program executables. I'm going to go into a bit of detail as to how executable files are understood by a modern virtual memory system to make this somewhat self-contained, but if you already know this part, skip down to "read-write data".

A modern executable file (e.g. ELF, PE/COFF) is typically arranged as a bunch of segments. A typical layout is the following segments in roughly this order:

- "Text", which is executable code. This segment should be mapped as read-only and executable.
- "Read only data", which is data that the user programs shouldn't modify. This typically includes data structures generated by the compiler for its own purposes (e.g. data structures to implement virtual calls, exception handling, static initialisation, etc), or truly read-only data such as static strings. This segment should be mapped as read-only and not executable.
- "Read-write data", which is data that is initialised but user programs can write to. This segment should be mapped as read-write, not executable, but also copy-on-write. Why copy-on-write? Because writing to that data should not modify the executable file that you're running!
- "[BSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss)", is static data that should be initialised to zero bytes and therefore doesn't need to take up any space in the executable file itself. This should be mapped as anonymous zero-fill memory.

When you run a program, this is how the operating system sets up a new virtual address space: it maps the segments from the executable in whatever way the executable requests.

By the way, the term "BSS" deserves some explanation. It was a pseudo-operation implemented on a particular assembler for the IBM 704 at some point in the mid-1950s, and it stood for "block starting symbol". By a series of historical accidents, the term has stuck and lives on today. Peter van der Linden suggested that "Better Save Space" might be a more suitable mnemonic.

Comment: And even in the case of a memory-mapped file, where intuitively you might think "surely, if I map a file from disk into memory, there must be a 1:1 correspondence of virtual memory addresses to disk blocks", you have *sparse files* (where there is no corresponding block stored on the disk at all), *encrypted files* (where the content of the on-disk block does not match the content of the in-memory block), *compressed files* (same), *log-structured file systems* (where the block you write to is not the block you read from), *file de-duplication* or *extent de-duplication*, and virtual or …

Comment: … network filesystems, where there isn't even a disk in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much. But does this mean that some virtual pages only map to RAM and not hard disk? I didn't quite understand how the virtual memory was connected to what you wrote.

Comment: It's also perfectly possible to map the same file to the same address space twice, or to different address spaces. @user394334, I will update my answer a bit.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand if there are some virtual adresses that only connect to RAM and not to disk?, so they are not saved to disk when they are replaced?

Comment: @user394334 It is possible in many operating systems to have a virtual memory segment that is anonymous (i.e. allocated memory not part of a file), but not to be swapped. In POSIX.4, the real-time extensions to POSIX, this is called "virtual memory locking". This is often the default in embedded and real-time operating systems, but typically must be asked for in general-purpose operating systems.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just have one last question. Can anonymous memory be in the virtual adresses, but they are not in hard disk?, and are not saved to hard disk when their physical memory is used for something else?

Comment: As I noted, the answer is yes. "Anonymous memory" means, more or less, what a user program thinks of as "allocated memory". That means it's usually in RAM/core, but it could be swapped out to swap space assuming there is any swap space.

Comment: iOS doesn't write virtual memory to disk, ever. The OS just doesn't do it. If you run out of RAM because of that, some application will be killed. Now in reality, I could buy a 20 TB hard drive, not very expensive. If an application tried to use all that as virtual memory, it would take so long, the application would be practically dead. Assume 100 MB/sec read and write, so that would be 200,000 seconds reading and 200,000 seconds writing, or 5 days. And 100 MB/sec is optimistic.

Comment: I once encountered an application that translated postscript to bitmap printing, and had bitmap equivalents of 20 postscript font files built in. Implemented as static arrays of const char. Ok, that still was only 20 MB, but I wouldn't be entirely shocked if someone added a five GB video file as a static array of const char to an application. Compiler would say "Help!!!!".

Comment: Mobile operating systems do have to be careful with the write cycle limit on flash storage.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping process is highly dynamic. Every process utilizes some part(s) of its virtual address space, which can be mapped to RAM or to disk. Mapping tables are used to establish the connection and are constantly adjusted to optimize memory accessibility (the most "active" pages should reside in RAM).

On 32 bits OSes, the maximum address space would be 4 GB per process, much smaller than current hard disks (typically 1 TB). On 64 bits OSs, the virtual size is much larger than any available hardware, but this limit is never approached.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please also explain if there are some virtual adresses that do not connect to the disk, but only to RAM?, and are not saved to disk when they are replaced?

Comment: @user394334: pages can be dropped only if the OS knows that they won't be used anymore.

Comment: Ok, but could there be a virtual page which only is connected to RAM, and when it is dropped it is not saved to the disk?, it only lives in RAM?

Comment: @user394334: why not ?

Comment: I don't know, I am just wondering if it could be so. Is it so that it could be so?

Comment: @user394334: what do you think ?

Comment: I would guess yes, but I am not sure.

Comment: @user394334 Assume you run an application, it uses virtual memory but there is always enough RAM, so nothing is ever written to disk. And then it exits, and whatever memory it used will never go to the disk. There is another situation: When you start an application, it is usually not loaded into RAM, but adressed as virtual memory, and stored exactly where the files of the application are stored. As soon as you try to execute some code, virtual memory will load it. But you cannot change the code, so it is never written back.

Comment: At an extreme, there are implementations for memset and calloc that don't actually set any bytes in RAM, but add virtual memory that is not on the hard drive, so when you access it, it's not in RAM, it's not on the disk, so it's set to zero. Calling calloc for 100GB could be very, very cheap - until you start using the memory.